# Varieties with ample canonical bundle contain no rational curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

MMP tells that a general type variety with no rational curve has ample canonical bundle.

I wonder if the converse is true? i.e. a variety with ample canonical bundle is of general type (of course) and contains no rational curve.

Comment: Can you write a reference to your first statement?

Comment: I have found it: Lemma 2.1 in S. Diverio, S. Trapani - *Quasi-negative holomorphic sectional curvature and positivity of the canonical bundle*, J. Differential Geom. **111** (2019) 303-314.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true. Take a general hypersurface of degree at least five in $\mathbb{P}^3$ containing a fixed line.

Comment: Or specifically consider a Fermat hypersurface.